# Change each symbol in string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I use this code to change each symbol in a string with different symbol:

```
$test = "უნდა არ არ ყაზახმა ერთი ორსავეს დათვალიერებული. გულის ჩავარდნილი დაეძებდა მათი";
$qart = array("/ა/", "/ბ/", "/გ/", "/დ/", "/ე/", "/ვ/", "/ზ/", "/თ/", "/ი/", "/კ/", "/ლ/", "/მ/", "/ნ/", "/ო/", "/პ/", "/ჟ/", "/რ/", "/ს/", "/ტ/", "/უ/", "/ფ/", "/ქ/", "ღ", "/ყ/", "/შ/", "/ჩ/", "/ც/", "/ძ/", "/წ/", "/ჭ/", "/ხ/", "/ჯ/", "/:ჰ:/");   
$eng = array("À","Á","Â", "Ã", "Ä", "Å", "Æ", "È", "É", "Ê", "Ë", "Ì", "Í", "Ï", "Ð", "Ñ", "Ò", "Ó", "Ô", "Ö", "×", "Ø", "Ù", "Ú", "Û", "Ü", "Ý", "Þ", "ß", "à", "á", "ã", "ä");
echo preg_replace($qart, $eng, $test);
```

but I get this error message:

> Warning: preg_replace()
>   [function.preg-replace]: No ending
>   delimiter '�' found in ...

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Why don’t you use `str_replace`?

Comment: is your charset correct?

Comment: what is the complete error message ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions are not the ideal solution for single character replacement. Use [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$pairs = array (
  'ა' => 'À',
  'ბ' => 'Á',
  'გ' => 'Â',
  // ...
);

$test = strtr($test, $pairs);
```

Comment: @Andy Read closely; `strtr` != `strstr`

Answer (score 0):

try preg_replace /u modifier if your string is in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern expression for [PHP’s PCRE functions](http://php.net/pcre) require [delimiters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters) that separate the pattern from optional modifiers. In your case one of the `$qart` values does not have `/` as delimiters (i.e. `ღ`).

But why do you use regular expressions anyway? I don’t see a need why you don’t use simple string replacement with [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace). It can take arrays for the search and replacement too.